# R: mapply over objects of two lists and return a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, loops, mapply

I have two GRange Lists and I am trying to apply countOverlaps function to each combination of the lists and return a list of results like this:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr1 <- GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr2"), ranges = IRanges(c(7,13), width = 3), strand = c("+", "-"))
gr2 <- GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr3"), ranges = IRanges(c(5,13), width = 3), strand = c("+", "-"))
grlA <- GRangesList("a" = gr1, "b" = gr2)

gr1 <- GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr2"), ranges = IRanges(c(1,13), width = 3), strand = c("+", "-"))
gr2 <- GRanges(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr3"), ranges = IRanges(c(3,13), width = 3), strand = c("+", "-"))
grlB <- GRangesList("c" = gr1, "d" = gr2)
```

I would like to get a list of object "a" and object "b" in grlA containing the results of the function for each value of grlB:

(list $a, $b and dataframes for c,d)

$c

a b

$d

a b

This works to get all the combinations of the list:

```
comb_apply <- function(f,..., MoreArgs=list()){
  exp <- unname(as.list(expand.grid(...,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
  do.call(mapply, c(list(FUN=f, SIMPLIFY=FALSE, MoreArgs=MoreArgs), exp))
 }

# This function is thanks to Michael Lawrence's help posted in the bioconductor package
t= comb_apply(function(i, j) countOverlaps(grlA[[i]], grlB[[j]]), seq_along(grlA), seq_along(grlB))
names(t)=apply(expand.grid(names(grlA), names(grlB)), 1, paste, collapse="_")
```

But then to get what I want (a list of data frames), I need to grep command to select out the data frames that are part of grlB and save them in a separate list, but this is veeery slow...

```
new=list()
for (i in names(grlB)) {
df = as.data.frame(t[grep(i,names(t))])
new[[length(new)+1]] <- df
}
```

Is there another way I can do this without grep maybe?
Thank you!

Comment: from GenomicRanges, Sorry I will add this!

Answer (score 0):

This data should not be in a list structure, because it has a predictable and consistent structure. I put it into a dataframe and shaped it to roughly the format you look like you're looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

t %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
  separate(variable, c("A", "B")) %>%
  spread(ID, value) %>%
  group_by(B) %>%
  do(result = my_function(.) )
```

Comment: Thank you bramtayl... I would like to output it in a list format though to apply other functions to each data frames (and there are many of them so it seems easier this way)...

Comment: If you want to apply a function to each subdataframe just use do (see the edit above)

Comment: I just don't know enough about the tidyr package as I never used it, I could also just split the resulting data frame into a list based on column A, but how do I save this to a data frame that I can use in other basic functions? Thanks again

Comment: I am also having trouble using the packages as I have to use a version of R that is not compatible with the dplyr packages... is there any way to do this in basic R? ok thanks...

Comment: Actually maybe this will do: d <- do.call(rbind, t)